# non-rigorous math books

Tags: reference-request

I’m self-studying physics and mathematics out of interest and I am looking for some non-rigorous (text)books on mathematics. Perhaps one book covering all areas relevant to physics or separate books in the areas of non-linear dynamics, differential equations, differential geometry, group theory, etc. 
I am explicitly looking for non-rigorous, intuitive approaches to these fields. I feel overly rigorous books make the material needlessly difficult (to me often impossible) and slow to read.  I am looking for things in the style of student’s guides, such as Dan Fleisch’s “A Student’s guide to vectors and tensors” but then more expanded:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11925464-a-student-s-guide-to-vectors-and-tensors?ac=1&from_search=true

Also, a mathematics book that shows the bigger picture on mathematics would be of interest. Something more or less popularising. 
Thanks!

Comment: T.W. Korner Fourier Analysis is a delight - lots of physics, differential equations too and while there are proofs, the presentation is leisurely and fairly informal

Comment: Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists by A. Zee is a good book of this sort for group theory - easy to read and relatively informal.

Comment: Pretty much any "in a nutshell" book works, especially if Zee is its author.